# Error setting up Redmine outgoing email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redmine-plugins

I am unable to setup email notifications on Redmine 1.0.3. I get following error when I ry sending a test mail:

An error occurred while sending mail (getaddrinfo: The storage control blocks were destroyed. )

My email.yml is as follows

```
production:
  delivery_method: :smtp
  smtp_settings:
    tls: true
    enable_starttls_auto: true
    address: "smtp.gmail.com" 
    port: '587'
    domain: "smtp.gmail.com" 
    authentication: :plain
    user_name: mymail@mydomain.com
    password: PASSWORD
```

Will appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Download following plugin and install it.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/action_mailer_optional_tls

It will help you to resolve the issue.